# Anchor tag Data attribute value is not returning correct value in react js

Tags: html, reactjs, typescript, html-dataset

Hi I am passing an object to anchor tag like this

```
<a
data-message= {message.data}
id={`${this.uid}_primaryAction_${id}`}
href="#"
onClick={
  this.handlePrimaryActionClick
}
>
  <span>{primaryButtonText}</span>
</a>
```

and in handlePrimaryActionClick function I am accessing the data like below.

```
private handlePrimaryActionClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const elem = event.target as HTMLElement
  const message = elem.parentElement.dataset.message;
};
```

But I am getting message as string , It should be object . Is anything wrong?

Comment: Why don't you pass data easily like `this.handlePrimaryActionClick(message.data)`

Comment: I passed event and data so it will create new instance on each render . Thats why i want to avoid thi